# Azure mobile app authentication back-end logic

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-mobile-services, backend

When a user authenticates on my app (by Google plus) I want to create a row in a Users table by the server side. I would not know how to do.
I think there is a function that is called when a users is authenticated.

My app is a mobile app with JavaScript back-end (Node.js).

Comment: up....................

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a callback that happens on successful authentication, but an easier way to implement this would be to require authentication on all of your endpoints, and then add the user information to a table if it doesn't already exist.

See this article for information on how to get user details in your Node.js app: [How to: Require Authentication for access to tables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#howto-tables-auth).